# Specifying priors in rstanarm for hierarchical model

Tags: r, linear-regression, bayesian

We are given the model $$
\begin{align*}
y_{ij} & \sim \mathsf{Normal}(\alpha_j + \beta x_i, \sigma^2)\\
\alpha_j & \sim \mathsf{Normal}(\gamma_0 + \gamma_1 u_j, \tau^2)
\end{align*}
$$ with priors $$ \begin{align*}
\beta, \gamma_0, \gamma_1 & \sim \mathsf{Normal}(0, 0.5^2)\\
\sigma, \tau & \sim \mathsf{Normal}_+(0, 0.25^2)
\end{align*}
$$  where we have $j$ counties and $i$ observations. I'm having trouble specifying all of my priors for rstanarm. What I have so far is

```
library(rstan)
library(rstanarm)
data(radon)

fit_lmer <- stan_glmer(log_radon ~ floor + (1 | county), 
                       data = radon,
                       prior_intercept = normal(0, 0.5),
                       prior_aux = normal(0, 0.25))
```

I'm just not entirely sure I properly specified everything.